# Microsoft Graph Toolkit in SPFx REACT web part

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I wanted to incorporate Microsoft Graph Toolkit  in my SPFx REACT webpart so I follow the instructions in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/toolkit/get-started
After

```
npm install @microsoft/mgt
```

I ran `gulp serve --nobrowser` and got there errors
[08:12:12] Starting subtask 'tsc'... [08:12:12] [tsc] typescript version: 3.3.4000 [08:12:24] Finished subtask 'tslint' after 14 s [08:12:26] Error - [tsc] node_modules/lit-html/ts3.4/lib/parts.d.ts(108,32): error TS1005: ';' expected. [08:12:26] Error - [tsc] node_modules/lit-html/ts3.4/lib/parts.d.ts(108,38): error TS1005: ';' expected. [08:12:26] Error - [tsc] node_modules/lit-html/ts3.4/lib/parts.d.ts(111,67): error TS1005: ',' expected. [08:12:26] Error - [tsc] node_modules/lit-html/ts3.4/lib/parts.d.ts(111,73): error TS1005: ',' expected. [08:12:26] Error - [tsc] node_modules/lit-html/ts3.4/lib/template-instance.d.ts(27,29): error TS1005: ',' expected. [08:12:26] Error - [tsc] node_modules/lit-html/ts3.4/lib/template-instance.d.ts(27,36): error TS1005: ',' expected. [08:12:26] Error - [tsc] node_modules/lit-html/ts3.4/lib/template-result.d.ts(21,31): error TS1005: ';' expected. [08:12:26] Error - [tsc] node_modules/lit-html/ts3.4/lib/template-result.d.ts(21,38): error TS1005: ';' expected. [08:12:26] Error - [tsc] node_modules/lit-html/ts3.4/lib/template-result.d.ts(24,65): error TS1005: ',' expected. [08:12:26] Error - [tsc] node_modules/lit-html/ts3.4/lib/template-result.d.ts(24,72): error TS1005: ',' expected. [08:12:26] Error - 'tsc' sub task errored after 15 s exited with code 2

Is there a typescript version contention between mgt and SPFx 1.10.0 ?

Is there a workaround this issue?

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Since no answer and I could not find the root of the issue, I changed the problematic .d.ts files.
If anyone is interested, replace the files in \node_modules\lit-html\ts3.4\lib
I wanted to upload the zip but no way to do it here.
I can send it to however wants it.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the ts version used is not compatible with mgt. Try upgrading to TypeScript 3.7 or above for your web part. You can see detailed instructions here: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/blogs/a-lap-around-microsoft-graph-toolkit-day-9-microsoft-graph-toolkit-sharepoint-provider/

Comment: Thank you. I tried just changing typescript but id did not help. your link makes it more clear.